# Parsing StackOverflow public data

Tags: support

There is a little problem I face while parsing a public dump of StackOverflow data published [here](http://2013.msrconf.org/challenge.php#challenge_data) for [MSR Mining Challenge](http://2013.msrconf.org/challenge.php). Thing is, that I am unable to programmatically digest the 18G postshistory.xml file.

So far, I have tried three different XML libraries in order to get through the whole thing.

- The standard Java 6 and Java 7 XMLStreamReader parsers fail with invalid character at... exception:

  ```
  javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1050673,5451]
  Message: Character reference "&# 
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:592)
  at com.softwaretrajectory.msr.stack.data.PrintFields.main(PrintFields.java:64)
  ```
- The VTDXml library, using VTDGenHuge:

  ```
  VTDGenHuge vtdGen = new VTDGenHuge();
  vtdGen.parseFile(fileLocation, false, VTDGenHuge.MEM_MAPPED);
  ```

  this fails to finish, parseFile returns false, no exception thrown.

  If I "insist" and continue with parsing anyway, it fails later for both methods: 
  when using AutoPilotHuge iterating over "row" elements, and when using VTDNavHuge for moving the cursor.
- Using Perl and XML::Twig with "processing an XML document chunk by chunk" approach - this one fails throwing similar exception and dumping core:

  ```
  reference to invalid character number at line 1050673, column 5445, byte 778177792 at /usr/lib/perl5/XML/Parser.pm line 187
  ```

Yes, I tried to remove this particular row from the XML, it fails on the another one, and so on... Moreover, I would like to keep these rows.

Taking in account my lack of experience with XML processing, and considerable amounts of time I am spending every time learning one of the "new way of doing it", I wonder, is there a known to work solution for this problem?

Comment: I remember there being errors like the ones you're seeing in the XML files when I tried to parse them eons ago. I thought they had them fixed by now. Are you using a recent data dump?

Comment: yes, I believe that it is The latest one, - it says "updated August 2012"

Comment: So, what's at line 1050673 and columns 5400-5500?

Comment: yes, right there, it is possible to use head/tail to extract the row: 
`head -1050673 posthistory.xml | tail -1`, the question is about [collection of papers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723397/compare-many-text-files-that-contain-duplicate-stubs-from-the-previous-and-nex)

Comment: sorry, it took me some time to get through with `cut`, the substring is: 
`e rise&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;b&gt;---end example---&#xC;&lt;/b&gt;" />`

Comment: `&#xC;` is not a valid entity according to the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets). That is causing the parser to choke (which is expected). You should post this as a bug because that's not valid XML; see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95505/invalid-characters-for-xml-parsing-in-posthistory-xml-from-stack-overflow

Comment: As far your problem goes, you will have to either remove the `&#xC;` entities or replace them with something else that's valid in XML. Read the section on C0 control characters here: http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/effectivexml/chapters/03.html

Comment: Thank you all for tips and links. Parsing is still going on, but it is well over 9.5M of records right now.
This is how I got through this particular problem: I used `sed` to filter out `&#xC;` and `&#x1B;`, like `sed 's/&#xC;//g' | sed 's/&#x1B;//g'` to produce corrected input for standard Java `XMLStreamReader` technique. 
Note, that on this corrected 18G XML file Perl Twig run out of memory, and VTDXml library still breaks without any exception. 
I have a workstation with Ubuntu and 8G RAM. Working code is [here](http://bit.ly/R46ASs)

Comment: How much memory do you have in your system? If u only have 8 i suggest u getting at least 8 more...

Comment: Well, it is useful suggestion, however all that I have is 8G station and 4G laptop. I think this might be an  extreme use case for vtd-xml (which I assume designed for different purpose) - low memory and somewhat incorrect XML, but I would appreciate a hint about where to look for the error - this way I could get it fixed and move further.